# ASP.NET Web APIからAzure Redis Cacheに接続できない

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, azure, redis

ASP.NET Web APIからAzure Redis Cacheにアクセスしたいのですが、
こちらの公式ドキュメントやブログ等を参考に、コントローラーを実装したのですが接続ができません。
[Azure Redis Cache の使用方法](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/#-6)
[ASP.NET Web API で Azure Redis Cache を利用する](http://gooner.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/08/26/azure-redis-cache/)

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer _connection;
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null || !_connection.IsConnected)
            {
                _connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("myredis.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=<password>");
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        try
        {
            IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
            cache.StringSet("foo", "bar");
            string foo = cache.StringGet("foo");

            return Ok(new { foo = foo });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }            
    }    
}
```

上記のコードだと、
IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
以降にブレークポイントが止まらず、
return Ok(new { foo = foo });
まで飛んでしまい、Exceptionも発生していません。
ただ、コンソールアプリケーションで、同じよなコードで実行すると、接続はできています。

```
class Program
{
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer _connection;
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null || !_connection.IsConnected)
            {
                _connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("myredis.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=<password>");
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
        cache.StringSet("foo", "bar");

        string foo = cache.StringGet("foo");

        Console.WriteLine(foo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Web APIのコントローラーからの呼び出しには、何か考慮しなければいけない点があるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

環境
Windows 8.1 Pro
Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
.NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

> 上記のコードだと、 IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
>   以降にブレークポイントが止まらず、 return Ok(new { foo = foo });
>   まで飛んでしまい、Exceptionも発生していません。

Relase ビルドではなく、Debug ビルドをデバッグ実行してますか？

また、確認されてるとは思いますが、微妙に接続文字列が間違っていたりはしないでしょうか？